# Getting a 'Bad Request' reply when trying to implement Websockets using direct tcp interface in Python

Tags: python, websocket

To better understand websocket internals, I am trying to implement them over tcp using python socket library. However I am not able to get past the HTTP upgrade handshake.

To start with I am making a simple HTTP GET request with just 4 headers. As described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Protocol_upgrade_mechanism#Upgrading_to_a_WebSocket_connection), these are the only ones which are mandatory. Here is my current code

```py
import socket

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect((server_ip, port))
client.send('GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: server_ip\r\nConnection: Upgrade\r\nUpgrade: websocket\r\n\r\n')
resp = client.recv(4096)
print resp
```

I am getting the following reply from the server

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Connection: close
Content-type: text/html
Content-Length: 11

Bad Request
```

What am I missing in the http header?

PS: The server side is a websocket server made using nodejs

Answer (score -1):

Try with:

```
import socket
import sys

# Create a TCP/IP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# Connect the socket to the port where the server is listening
server_address = ('server_ip', ip_port)
sock.connect(server_address)

try:
    message = 'This is the message.  It will be repeated.'
    print("Sending: " + message)
    sock.sendall(message)

    # Look for the response
    amount_received = 0
    amount_expected = len(message)

    while amount_received < amount_expected:
        data = sock.recv(16)
        amount_received += len(data)
        print("Received: " + data)

finally:
    print("Closing socket")
    sock.close()
```

Using websockets library:

```
pip install websockets
```

Code:

```
import asyncio
import websockets

async def test():
    async with websockets.connect('ws://url') as websocket:
        await websocket.send("hello")
        response = await websocket.recv()
        print(response)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(test())
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, this is just establishing a normal tcp connection to the server and exchanging data. What I am specifically looking for is websocket implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, maybe I was not clear in the question. I am trying to implement websockets from scratch by just using tcp sockets and constructing the websocket packets myself. This is part of exercise in better understanding the underlying details of websockets. So I am afraid your solution of using websocket library will not be suitable.